# How to extend mysqli that it is silent like calling with @

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First my class:

```
    class database extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($dbInfo) {
            parent::__construct($dbInfo['host'], $dbInfo['user'], $dbInfo['pass'], $dbInfo['dbname']);

            if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                        . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            $this->set_charset("utf8");
        }
    }

        $dbInfo = array(
            'host'      => "localhost",
            'user'      => "user",
            'pass'      => "pass",
            'dbname'    => "name"
        );



$db = new database($dbInfo);
```

Here I will get this errormessage:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'name' in <b>/www/test/ajax_artikellist.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
Connect Error (1044) Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'name'
```

I would like to have only this as error:

```
Connect Error (1044) Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'name'
```

What I have to do to get it?

Comment: You want to receive _less_ debug information?

Comment: right. I wont only my "Connect Error" line.

Comment: Can I ask why? You would be getting rid of all the information that actually points you to where the error is.

Comment: in production i do not want to show users more errors

Comment: In production, your user should not see _any_ errors. You want your user to see "_Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'name'_"?

Comment: and: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'name' are enough hints

Comment: to show not any error ist a solution, but better way is to show "my error-message"

Comment: Basically, your whole idea is wrong. You don't need to extend anything, least you want to die. Please read [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#raise)